# Can we send multiple Properties in Json of Analytics(IBM MobileFirst)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-analytics

I was asked for a usecase where I have to filter ActionEvents on type of Page that action is being is being called from.

Example

use case: I have a login page and I have to capture analytics of its events

Can I do something like this

```
String json = {"PageLevel":"LoginPage","ActionLevel":"LoginButton"};
WLAnalytics analytics=new WLAnalytics();
analytics.log(message, new JSONObject(json));
```

Will this work... can we create custom chart with first property being ActionLevel and filter it as per PageLevel.

Answer (score 0):

No this will not work. Custom analytics can only be logged in key value pairs i.e. you cannot send two key value pairs in one JSON object. This is a good idea though, I recommend you submit an RFE.

[Submit a Feature Request](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=submitRfe)